# Xamarin.Forms Resource file is not found

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I did everything exactly as in this simple guide of how to access strings from another file anywhere in the Xamarin.forms project (in xaml and c#).

(https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows)

However, it will simply not found my resouces, even If I set the build options to embedded resource.

THIS DOESNT WORK:

```
            <Label
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                FontFamily="arial"
                FontSize="12"
                TextColor="#272727"
                Text="{x:Static local:AppResources.BgColor}" 
                HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                VerticalOptions="Start"/>
```

[Screenshot of resx file and browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vejX0.jpg)

It should work accordning to the manual but im getting: "Type AppResources not found in xmlns dr-namespace:app4.Renderer.

Please help me out here. Otherwise I have so many hardcoded strings in code and xaml files...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the XAML file, add:

```
xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resx"
```

MyApp = namespace;
Resx = folder where the resource file is

Comment: Stil it says "namespace not found"

Answer (score -1):

The errors shows it can not find the class `AppResources` under the path `app4.Renderer` .

You have to ensure the path (namespace + folder + classname) is set correctly .

Change the `local` in scheme as

```
 xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:App4.Resx"
```

Comment: U mean I should change it in the label text property? Sorry I cannot follow,..

Comment: No , change the `local` definition in xaml .

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have change this it says "namespace not found" .. :(

Comment: Could you provide a minimum ,simple project which could reproduce the issue ? You can upload to github and share your link here .

Comment: at the moment no, since the project is on hold. ill report soon :)